API Flask and Docker compose issue
I'm having a little issue understanding how to access an endpoint from an api i'm hosting because this is my first time using docker compose. The isue is (i think) i'm setting the PORT 5000 for the Flask Api but when i try http://123.43.210.230:5000 (example) to hit the endpoint i'm getting this error:
(https://i.sstatic.net/TMt1Y3BJ.png)
Flask configuration in my script:

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)


docker-compose.yml :

    version: '3.8'
    services:
      flask-app:
        build: .
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
        depends_on:
          - selenium-standalone
        environment:
          - FLASK_ENV=development
        env_file:
          - .env
    
      selenium-standalone:
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
        ports:
          - "4444:4444"
          - "7900:7900"
        shm_size: 2gb


Dockerfile:

    FROM python:3.8-slim
    
    
    WORKDIR /app
    
    
    COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
    COPY . .
    
    
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    
    
    EXPOSE 5000
    
    
    CMD ["python", "arg.py"]


The structure of the project:

    .env
    requirements.txt
    arg.py
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml


When i entered the command docker compose up -d everything seems to run okay, i check the container with the Api and it appears to have started just fine but when i try to hit the endpoint that error shows. I've checked that the ports are open and the firewall disabled so i don't know what might be causing the problem. If i try http://123.43.210.230:4444 or http://123.43.210.230:7900 it shows selenium messages just fine so i'm just having trouble with my Api.
Update:
I've tried curl http://localhost:5000 in the VM and it did hit the endpoint but not why from outside?

Do you need to port forward the VM?

I don't know, the weird thing is that if i use docker build (instead of docker compose) i can hit the endpoint from google chrome but not this way, sadly the api doesn't work without selenium so i was trying to get it with docker compose

I assume you mean docker run. Can you share that command? Maybe something didn't convert

I'm using docker compose up -d

Where are you trying to run this at? Your local dev machine or a hosted linux instance or what?

It's running in a digitalocean droplet, a VM with ubuntu

I found the answer in changing the docker-compose.yml file a bit:
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  flask-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - selenium-standalone
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - my-network
  
  selenium-standalone:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "7900:7900"
    shm_size: 2gb
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge

